# Removing space before Section in Table of Contents when using Article

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

How can I remove the vertical spacing before each section in the table of contents from a 'article' documentclass?

Comment: the question's title means chapter, the question's body refers to section. Btw. before sections there's no space, but before chapters there is.

Comment: Hugo, please also update the title if you want change the spacing of section lines instead of chapter lines. Note that simple changing `\l@section` to `\l@chapter` in Gonzalo's answer might not work.

Comment: It actually works... I meant about referring to section, because chapter does not exist in the 'article' documentclass. Yes, I made a lot of mistakes in this question, but the answer's still valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine `\l@section` as implemented in `article.cls` and suppress (or comment out) the line `\addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%` responsible for the extra space. Simply add these lines to the preamble of your document:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with the [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesecskip}{0pt}
```

will do what you want.

Comment: Not only did that work, it also solved a problem I had with styles! Thx!

Answer (score 1):

To decrease the spacing without copy/pasting the cryptic source code of `\l@section` just add the negative spacing before the original `\l@section` command

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@l@section\l@section 
\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{\vspace*{-5pt}\old@l@section{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
```

Or, for `report` class:

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@l@chapter\l@chapter 
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{\vspace*{-5pt}\old@l@chapter{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
```